# Can I remove these walls?

Tags: walls, load-bearing, demolition, engineering

I'm doing kitchen renovation and want to remove a few walls. Those are on the first floor of a 2 story house(no basement).
I've opened a few of them and did my best to provide all the pictures.
I opened the ceiling and checked how joists run above those walls. Looks like they just run through them a few feet past the walls I'm considering to remove.

1&2 is a small closet. 3&4 is has only 1 wire inside which is going into the slab.
the niche between those walls was supposed to be a built in desk

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

1. Can I remove them (Wall 1,2,3,4) and make the back wall flush?
2. Should I reinforce those joists? For example I can do sistering with a plywood from both sides of them.

Edit:

[image]

Wall 1/2 Intersection with trusses:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You shall pay a structural engineer to inspect. The walls seem strange.

Comment: Those walls do not seem to be for cupboards/pantry or something useful.  Must consider that they are for load bearing.  Most people do not put walls like that up without a good reason.

Comment: At a minimum, there is electrical work inside walls 1 & 2 that will need to be moved. What's inside that box out for walls 3 & 4? They could be plumbing or HVAC chases (odd, I know, without a basement to run from, but we can't see inside them, just the ceiling above).

Comment: 1 & 2 is a small closet. and 3 & 4 has only single wire inside in the bottom which seems to be going into slab but I think I can hide the whole cable it into the slab.

Comment: the niche between those walls was supposed to be a built in desk

Comment: I'm sure you're aware that if you need extra cable to reroute the wiring that there are rules about how the junctions can be made. Loads of questions here about that, if you're not sure.

Answer (score 1):

1 and 2 don't seem structural, because they don't go under the strong points of the truss-joists.

3 and 4 are hard to tell, you're asking me "Is this wall holding something up" I can't see from here.

I would guess probably not structual, but they don't seem to serve any other purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 3&4 is has only 1 wire inside which is going into the slab. the niche between those walls was supposed to be a built in desk. I think that this was the reason of that wall. Also I've added 3 pics to my question where you can see what's above wall 3/4 (You can see nails coming out from it) and intersections of trusses / walls 1,2. Could you look at it? maybe it will give you a better picture of structure?